# Taylor series, Finding the sum of a series

Tags: calculus

I was given the following function:

[image]

The area of convergence is [-5/3,7/3), I want to represent the series as a function, what is the framework? what are the steps for such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln(1-u)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}{n}$. Note that $\frac{(3x-1)^n}{6^n}=\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{6} \right)^n$

Comment: The series starts at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hinting: for $\;|z|<1\;$ , we have

$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\implies \frac1{z(1-z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n-1}\;\stackrel{\text{Integ.}}\implies\;\log|z|-\log (1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u^n = \frac{1}{1 - u}$ for $|u| < 1$. Integrating this series, we get

$$ -\ln(1 - u) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u^n}{n} $$

and this series converges also for $u = -1$ to $-\ln(2)$ by Abel's theorem.

Your series is then obtained by taking $u = \frac{3x - 1}{6}$ resulting in

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3x-1)^n}{n \cdot 6^n} = -\ln \left(1 - \frac{3x - 1}{6} \right) = \ln(6) - \ln(7 - 3x). $$

Note that if $x \in \left[ -\frac{5}{3}, \frac{7}{3} \right]$ then indeed $-1 \leq u < 1$ and so the domains of convergence fit.